# Mocking a class which uses static void method of another class

Tags: java, junit, mocking, powermock

```
public class ProjectIdInitializer {
    public static void setProjectId(String projectId) {
        //load spring context which i want  to escape in my test
    }
}

public class MyService {
    public Response create(){
        ...
        ProjectIdInitializer.setProjectId("Test");
    }
}

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ProjectIdInitializer.class})
public class MyServiceTest{
    @InjectMocks
    private MyService myServiceMock ;

    public void testCreate() {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ProjectIdInitializer.class);
        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(ProjectIdInitializer.class, "setProjectId", Mockito.any(String.class));
        // Does not work,still tries to load spring context
        Response response=myServiceMock .create();
    }
```

How can i make sure that nothing happens if ProjectIdInitializer.setProjectId() is called from myservice?

Comment: If it turns out to be true, that only PowerMock would help you ... consider if there if your design could be changed to **not** use static this way; and therefore to avoid PowerMock. (simply because PowerMock is best used ... by avoiding it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*As stated in comments, you should be aware that many things might break because of PowerMock.*

You need to use PowerMock runner, something like that:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(ProjectIdInitializer.class)
public class MyServiceTest{
  private MyService myService = new MyService();

  public void testCreate()
  {
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(ProjectIdInitializer.class);
    PowerMockito.doNothing().when(ProjectIdInitializer.class, "setProjectId", Mockito.any(String.class));

    Response response=myService.create();
  }
}
```

see also [this doc.](https://code.google.com/p/powermock/wiki/GettingStarted)

---

This self contained sample:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(A.ProjectIdInitializer.class)
public class A {
    private MyService myService = new MyService();

    @Test
    public void testCreate() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(ProjectIdInitializer.class);
        PowerMockito.doNothing().when(ProjectIdInitializer.class, "setProjectId", Mockito.any(String.class));

        System.out.println("Before");
        Response response = myService.create();
        System.out.println("After");
    }

    public static class ProjectIdInitializer {
        public static void setProjectId(String projectId) {
            //load spring context which i want  to escape in my test
            System.out.println(">>>>>> Game over");
        }
    }

    public static class Response {
    }

    public static class MyService {
        public Response create() {
            // ...
            ProjectIdInitializer.setProjectId("Test");
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

outputs:

```
Before
After
```

As expected

Comment: I have annotated my unit test with PowerMockRunner.Please see the edit.It doesn't work though

Comment: @RC. Consider putting a big red "warning" on your answer - as PowerMock  is rarely "the good answer" to "static testing issues". PowerMock can break many other tools, for example to measure coverage. So the "need to use PowerMock" often translates to "change your design".

Comment: @EddyG, ok. I will add a warning

Comment: @RC. Hmm, did you mean to write "PowerMock**ito**"?

Comment: @EddyG I don't understand, where?

Comment: This does not work.Can you point if something else is wrong here

Comment: @RC. Well, in the answer that I am looking at, it says "PowerMockito" two times.